# Removing index.php from url breaks member login form

Tags: members, login

I was just implementing a member login form that worked fine until I tried to remove the index.php from the url with the following .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In the general configuration "Name of your site's index page" is blanked out.

This is the member login form:

```
{exp:member:login_form return="http://www.website.com/index.php/projects_client"}
                    <div class="formBox">
                        <h1>Log in</h1>
                        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                        <div class="field">
                            <span class="label"><label for="username">Username:</label></span>
                            <input type="username" maxlength="32" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                        </div> <!-- /.field -->
                        <div class="field">
                            <span class="label"><label for="password">Password:</label></span>
                            <input maxlength="32" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        </div> <!-- /.field -->
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <button type="submit" class="button primary">Continue</button>
                            {if auto_login}
                            <div class="field cb">
                                <span class="label cb"><label><input type="checkbox" name="auto_login" value="1"> Remember me</label></span>
                            </div> <!-- /.field.cb -->
                            {/if}
                        </div> <!-- /.buttons -->
                    </div> <!-- /.formBox -->
                    <p><a href="{path='member/forgot_password'}">Forgot your <span>password</span>?</a></p>
                {/exp:member:login_form}
```

The return url is temporary, I wan't it to be something like this: redirect="projects_client"

When the index.php is removed and I submit the form I'm just redirected to the homepage. I'm not logged in. When I put the index.php back (Comment the .htaccess file and put index.php back in the general configuration: "Name of your site's index page") It's working again.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: Try to remove index.php from return="http://www.website.com/index.php/projects_client"

Comment: ever figure this out I am having the same issue (ref: LFL)